# Check if value can be serialized to JSON in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I've got this code:

```
function evaluate(expression, context, callback)
{
    try {
        var evaluated = safeEval(expression, context);
        callback(JSON.stringify({data: evaluated}));
    } catch(err) {
        callback(JSON.stringify({error: err.name + ': ' + err.message}));
    }
}
```

Callback here represents some function which accepts arbitary JSON data encoded into string format.

I want to somehow handle the situation when `evaluated` happens to be unserializeable into JSON (for example, if it's `undefined` or `function` or whatever else what can't be serialized properly). How could I do this?

**UPD:** Small example of unexpected behaviour:

```
evaluate("a.b", {a:{}}, function(s){console.log(s);});    // Logs '{}', but should throw
```

Comment: Your code should work as expected. Did u face any issue in above?

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda my code works as expected either if expressions throws an exception or evaluates normally, but when it does not throw but provides an entity unserializeable to JSON, it simply returns `{}`, which is unacceptible for me in my case.

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda I've updated my question with small example

Comment: Well, `"{}"` is a perfectly valid JSON, so you'll need to add additional checks manually.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes, the question actually is how to check if `JSON.stringify({data:something})` returns `'{}'` or `'{"data": "something_encoded"}'`

Comment: The stringified version of `{data: undefined}` is `{}`. In your example `s.data` would return `undefined` which is perfectly fine. So is problem  at a later stage e.g. with iterating over `s` or an `in` check? So if you don't want this then check if `evaluated` is `undefined` and throw the error for that case.

Comment: @t.niese yes, I've got another app which awaits for the explicit presense of "data" field in JSON.

Comment: @t.niese I can't simply check for `undefined`. For example, `JSON.stringify({data:function(){}})` also returns `"{}"`, and I bet this is not the only case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment you could check if `evaluated` itself can be stringified, or if ti would return `undefined`. If it can be stringified you can complete finalized the json response using `'{"data":'+stringified+'}'`. Doing this concatenation is save, because `stringified` would be a valid JSON value.

```
function evaluate(expression, context, callback) {
  try {
    var evaluated = safeEval(expression, context);
    var stringified = JSON.stringify(evaluated);

    if (typeof stringified === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error('could not be stringified');
    }

    callback('{"data":' + stringified + '}');
  } catch (err) {
    callback(JSON.stringify({
      error: err.name + ': ' + err.message
    }));
  }
}
```

If the response is more complex, with more then the `data` field then this solution might be better:

```
function evaluate(expression, context, callback) {
  try {
    var evaluated = safeEval(expression, context);
    var stringified = JSON.stringify({
      data: evaluated
    });

    if (typeof JSON.parse(stringified).data === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error('could not be stringified');
    }

    callback(stringified);
  } catch (err) {
    callback(JSON.stringify({
      error: err.name + ': ' + err.message
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that should work. I'll wait a bit for a simpler solution before accepting this answer.